# How to supress the creation of a column when ordering a dataframe?

Tags: r

I am an r newbie, familiar with relational databases like SQLServer.

When I use

```
df2 <-df1[order(df1$coeff, decreasing =TRUE),]
```

I discover that a blank column is created in df2 to hold the order

Thus when I use

```
head(df2)
```

I see the new column

[image: df2]

I don't want to see that. I just want to see the top rows in order.

How do I stop this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a new column, but the row.names reordered.  We can set it to `NULL` to get the default row names order

```
row.names(df2) <- NULL
```

Or use a sequence to assign

```
row.names(df2) <- seq_len(nrow(df2))
```

---

This wouldnt be an issue with `arrange` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
         arrange(desc(coeff))
```